# Same toolbar color on all Activities

Tags: android, background-color

In my application i have 3 `activities`,each `activity` has same `Toolbar` with custom style (with background color blue) is included.

From `Activity-A` user can change background color of `toolbar` (from blue to red). It works properly on `Activity-A`'s `toolbar`,but when i go to `Activity-B` from `Activity-A` color of `toolbar` is previous one (background color is blue not red).

My `toolbar` is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:theme="@style/myToolbarTheme"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="48dp"
      android:padding="0dp">
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Custom Style is:

```
 <style name="myToolbarTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/themeBlue</item>
</style>
```

To change background color of a toolbar am using,

```
     toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.themeRed));
```

So my question is, how can i set same color to a toolbar on each activity? Please suggest me.

Thank you

Comment: define style for generic toolbar color

Comment: Can you explain how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use color primary in your style

```
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
```

[image]

more reference [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

Comment: does it reflect change on all `Activities`?

Comment: @User_1191 Yes if you use it as your default theme in your manifest's <application> tag

Comment: but then how i change the toolbar background color programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create one more activity is `BaseActivity` (extends `Activity`)
All of your activities (in this case it is 3) will extends `BaseActivity`
Then you will write code for change the toolbar color in `BaseActivity`
Finally, on each sub activity, call the code for change toolbar color in `BaseActivity`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>
```

Apply to Toolbar

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_questions_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Theme.DesignDemo"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```